# Design pattern for building data model through different levels

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a data model that has several attributes

```
class MyData {
    public string attr1;
    public string attr2;
    public string attr3;
}
```

These attributes values are not assigned at a common place, instead, this data model is passed around in several functions where values are assigned. For example,

```
public void method1(final MyData data) {
    ...
    data.attr1 = "val1";
    ...
    method2(data);
}

public void method2(final MyData data) {
    ...
    data.attr2 = "val2";
    ...
    method3(data);
}

public void method3(final MyData data) {
    ...
    data.attr3 = "val3";
    ...
    finalProcess(data);
}
```

My question is, what is the best practice of building data model in this case? People say data immutable guarantees thread safety, if the attributes can be only set once, would that serve the purpose? Is there any non-hacky way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description, I think Builder pattern will help in this case.

```
MyData.Builder builder= new MyData.Builder(); 

public void method1(MyData.Builder builder) {
    ...
    builder.attr1 = "val1";
    ...
    method2(builder);
}

public void method2(MyData.Builder builder) {
    ...
    builder.attr2 = "val2";
    ...
    method3(builder);
}

public void method3(MyData.Builder builder) {
    ...
    builder.attr3 = "val3";
    ...
    finalProcess(builder.build());
}
```

MyData class can be made immutable which makes it threadsafe

Answer (score 0):

If the fields are public, it is difficult to have some sort of control over MyData, because everyone can access and change the values. Start by setting the fields private and provide access to them only via methods:

```
class MyData {
    private String attr1;
    private String attr2;
    private String attr3;

    public void setAttr1(String attr1) {
        this.attr1=attr1;
    }
    // Other setter methods..
}
```

In general you delegate the creation of an object to a factory. Then you can extend the factory to build different types of your object. But there are other approaches under the name of Creational Design Patterns.